# Arrays in c++ and windows form

Tags: .net, arrays, opencv, bitmap, c++-cli

I am making a project of image processing using GUI , anyways I want to convert the bitmap image into a Mat (*opencv*) so I loop through the bitmap image and get the values of the Red component in order to place it in a Mat variable in the cpp that I have , because whenever I declare a Mat variable inside the Form that have all the functions of the GUI I get an error so I do as follow

```
    #pragma once



namespace TestGUI1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for TestForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class TestForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        TestForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //

        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~TestForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    public: int static test;

    public:  Bitmap^ picture;
    public:  
            int static width;
            int static height;

            static int* Red;

             //static int  Green;
             //static int  Blue;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox2;




    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->pictureBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox2))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 372);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &TestForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 346);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(639, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &TestForm::textBox1_TextChanged);
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(295, 304);
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this->pictureBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(330, 12);
            this->pictureBox2->Name = L"pictureBox2";
            this->pictureBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(329, 304);
            this->pictureBox2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->pictureBox2->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // TestForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(671, 407);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"TestForm";
            this->Text = L"TestForm";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox2))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

            //Select Image from computer using the dialog box
            OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
            textBox1->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName;


            picture = gcnew Bitmap(openFileDialog1->FileName);
            width = picture->Width;
            height = picture->Height;
            Red = new int[width*height];
            int Red1[50][50];
            pictureBox1->Image = picture;
            // Loop through the images pixels to reset color.
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = picture->GetPixel(x, y);

                    //Red[x + y] = picture->GetPixel(x,y).R;
                    //cout << Red[x + y] << "  ";
                    //Red1[x][y] = picture->GetPixel(x, y).R;
                    //Red[x + y] = pixelColor.R;
                    Red1[x][y] = pixelColor.R;
                    cout << Red1[x][y] << " " ;
                }
                cout << endl;

            }


    }

};
}
```

The array that I declared inside the button function only takes the real values of the Red comp, while the Array that I declared as `public:static int* Red` to be able to access it in the main function is filled only with 255 in all it's values 
and I can't really know what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing a 2D array of size `width` and `height`:

```cpp
for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
  for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    do_something(arr[y][x]);
  }
}
```

Traversing the 1D version of the same array:

```cpp
for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
  for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    do_something(arr[y * width + x]; //NOT arr[y + x]
  }
}
```